# Forcing a tab stop on a hidden element? Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[**The site is here**](http://ipalaces.org/hosting/register.php)

I have opt to using the radiobutton's labels as customized buttons for them. This means the radio inputs themselves are display:none. Because of this, the browsers don't tab stop at the radio labels, but I want them to.

I tried forcing a tabindex to them, but no cigar.

I have came up with just putting a pointless checkbox right before the labels, and set it to width: 1px; and height 1px; which seems to only really work on chrome & safari.

So do you have any other ideas for forcing a tab stop at those locations without showing an element?

Edit:

Just incase someone else comes by this, this is how I was able to insert small checkboxes into chrome & safari using JQuery:

```
if ($.browser.safari) {
    $("label[for='Unlimited']").parent().after('<input style="height:1px; width:1px;" type="checkbox">');
    $("label[for='cash']").parent().after('<input style="height:1px; width:1px;" type="checkbox">');
    $("label[for='Length12']").parent().after('<input style="height:1px; width:1px;" type="checkbox">');
}
```

Note: $.browser.webkit was not becoming true...so I had to use safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the radio input hidden, but set `tabindex="0"` on the `<label>` element of reach radio input.

(A tab index of 0 keeps the element in tab flow with other elements with an unspecified tab index which are still tabbable.)

Comment: This does not work, even putting tabindex="0" on the labels of a hidden radio input seem to be skipped. Atleast in chrome.

Comment: @Brian, Seems I was wrong; `tabindex` non non-form elements is an extension in some browsers (e.g. IE and Firefox, which is what I tested with).

Comment: Well, if it works with firefox and IE (the 2 most popular browsers) then this will work as a solution. Seems to actually workout because the checkbox method works best for chrome & safari...so I will use checkbox method for those 2...everything else I'll use tabindex=0

Comment: Check my edit to see the example on how I used JQuery to insert small checkboxes

Comment: Respectfully @strager, I am not sure this will work. My understanding is that <label> elements will pass over focus to their associated control elements on TAB//focus events. I think it might require some JavaScript hacking but it would work.

Answer (score 11):

a working solution in my case to enable tab selection / arrow navigation was to set the opacity to zero rather than a "display: none"

```
.styled-selection input {
    opacity: 0;         // hide it visually
    z-index: -1;        // avoid unintended clicks
    position: absolute; // don't affect other elements positioning
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you separate the label from any field and set a tabIndex you can tab to it and capture mouse and key events. It seems more sensible to use buttons or inputs with type="button",
but suit yourself.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input value="today">
        <label tabIndex="0" onfocus="alert('label');">Label 1</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative answer that I think has not been mentioned yet. For recent work I've been reading the Mozilla Developer Docs [MDN Docs, Forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms), especially the Accessibility Section [MDN Docs, Accessible HTML(5)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML), for information related to keyboard accessibility and form structure.

One of the specific mentions in the Accessibility section is to use HTML5 elements when and where possible -- they often have cross-browser and more accessible support by default (not always true, but clear content structure and proper elements also help screen reading along with keyboard accessibility).

**Anyway**, here's a JSFiddle: [JSFiddle::Keyboard Accessible Forms](https://jsfiddle.net/trkdwxa6/)

Essentially, what I did was:

1. shamelessly copy over some of the source code from a *Mozilla source code to a JSFiddle* (source in the comments of the fiddle)
2. create a TEXT-type  and assign it the "**readonly**" HTML5 attribute
3. add attribute **tabindex="0"** to the readonly
4. *Modify the "readonly" CSS* for that input element so it looks "blank" or hidden"

**HTML**

```
<title>Native keyboard accessibility</title>
<body>

  <h1>Native keyboard accessibility</h1>

  <hr>

  <h2>Links</h2>

  <p>This is a link to <a href="https://www.mozilla.org">Mozilla</a>.</p>

  <p>Another link, to the <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org">Mozilla Developer Network</a>.</p>

  <h2>Buttons</h2>

  <p>
    <button data-message="This is from the first button">Click me!</button>
    <button data-message="This is from the second button">Click me too!
    </button>
    <button data-message="This is from the third button">And me!</button>
  </p>

  <!-- "Invisible" HTML(5) element -->
  <!-- * a READONLY text-input with modified CSS... -->
  <hr>
  <label for="hidden-anchor">Hidden Anchor Point</label>
  <input type="text" class="hidden-anchor" id="hidden-anchor" tabindex="0" readonly />
  <hr>

  <h2>Form</h2>

  <form name="personal-info">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Info</legend>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Fill in your name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="age">Enter your age:</label>
        <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="mood">Choose your mood:</label>
        <select id="mood" name="mood">
          <option>Happy</option>
          <option>Sad</option>
          <option>Angry</option>
          <option>Worried</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>


  <script>
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      addHandler(buttons[i]);
    }

    function addHandler(button) {
      button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var message = e.target.getAttribute('data-message');
        alert(message);
      })
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

**CSS Styling**

```
input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

a:hover, input:hover, button:hover, select:hover,
a:focus, input:focus, button:focus, select:focus {
  font-weight: bold;
}


.hidden-anchor {
  border: none; 
  background: transparent!important;
}
.hidden-anchor:focus {
  border: 1px solid #f6b73c;
}
```

BTW, you can edit the CSS rule for **.hidden-anchor:focus** to remove the highlight for the hidden anchor if you want. I added it just to "prove" the concept here, but it still works invisibly as requested.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

My preference:

```
.tab-only:not(:focus) {
  position: fixed;
  left: -999999px;
}
```

```
<button class="tab-only">Jump to main</button>
```

Comment: I used this method, but for all input selector, and with position: absolute. Works great, and I can keep my custom-styled label:before pseudo-element checkbox in place. I also had to add special CSS styling for input:focus + label and input:active + label so you could tell which option you were on while tabbing through the list, since the browser won't do this automatically when your input is a pseudo.

Answer (score 0):

Another great option would be to nest your *input + div* in a *label* and hide the input by setting *width and height to 0px* instead of *display: none*

This method even allows you to use pseudo-classes like :focus or :checked by using *input:pseudo + styleDiv*

```
<label>
    <input type="radio">
    <div class="styleDiv">Display text</div>
</label>

input
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}

input + .styleDiv
{
    //Radiobutton style here
    display: inline-block
}

input:checked + .styleDiv
{
   //Checked style here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Discard the radio-buttons and instead; keep some hidden fields in your code, in which you store the selected value of your UI components.

Comment: This would require rewriting everything that is already setup, I am looking for a more simple solution.

The reason I did radio buttons to avoid writing code to require an input of some sort...etc.

Comment: Sometimes you run into situations where you need to refactor a bit... And as far as I can see, all you need is a JavaScript click-event on each of your tabs, which takes the ID of the currently selected tab and puts it in a hidden field. Then it's just a matter of changing your server-side code to use values from the hidden fields instead of the radio-buttons.